find consecutive non NA values rowwise up to a specific column
I have this sample data frame
df <- data.frame(New=c("X2", "k5", "N30","N40", "K5", "S12", "K5", "K5"),
K_10=c(NA, NA, 3, 4,0,2,NA, NA), 
K_11=c(NA, NA, NA, 4,0,3,NA, NA), 
K_12=c(NA, 2, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,0), 
K_13=c(0, 3, 5, NA,0,5,NA,NA), 
K_14=c(NA, 3, 1, 2,10,10,NA,NA),
K_15=c(NA, 2, 3, 5,15,10,NA,2),
K_16=c(NA, 10, 1, 6,43,10,NA,56),
K_17=c(NA, 5, 1, 3,1,10,NA,23),
K_18=c(NA, 6, 4, 2,0,10,NA,12),
K_19=c(NA, 3, 8, NA,3,10,NA,90),
K_20=c(NA, 3, 19, 2,6,10,NA,59),
K_21=c(NA, 3, 10, 2,8,10,NA,11),
K_22=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,9,10,NA,10),
K_23=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,90,10,NA,9))

  df  
  New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23
1  X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2  k5   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3
3 N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA
4 N40    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2
5  K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90
6 S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10
7  K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
8  K5   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9

I want to create a column that will check rowwise  if there are at least 6 consecutive Non-NAs from K_11 up to K_18
In addition, I want to create a second column that will check rowwise  if there are at least 6 consecutive Non-NAs from K_11 up to K_18, only when New=k5
Finally, I want to create a third column that
will count rowwise how many Nas there are from K_11 up to K_18, only when there are  at least 6 consecutive Non-Nas in that row
So my output should be this one
df_new <- data.frame(New=c("X2", "k5", "N30","N40", "K5", "S12", "K5", "K5"),
K_10=c(NA, NA, 3, 4,0,2,NA, NA), 
K_11=c(NA, NA, NA, 4,0,3,NA, NA), 
K_12=c(NA, 2, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,0), 
K_13=c(0, 3, 5, NA,0,5,NA,NA), 
K_14=c(NA, 3, 1, 2,10,10,NA,NA),
K_15=c(NA, 2, 3, 5,15,10,NA,2),
K_16=c(NA, 10, 1, 6,43,10,NA,56),
K_17=c(NA, 5, 1, 3,1,10,NA,23),
K_18=c(NA, 6, 4, 2,0,10,NA,12),
K_19=c(NA, 3, 8, NA,3,10,NA,90),
K_20=c(NA, 3, 19, 2,6,10,NA,59),
K_21=c(NA, 3, 10, 2,8,10,NA,11),
K_22=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,9,10,NA,10),
K_23=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,90,10,NA,9),
Con_11_18=c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),
 Con_11_18_New=c("Not applicable", TRUE, "Not applicable", "Not applicable",TRUE, "Not applicable","FALSE","FALSE"),
count_NA_11_18_New=c("Not applicable", 1,2, 2,0,1,"Not applicable","Not applicable"))
df_new

df_new
  New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23 Con_11_18  Con_11_18_New count_NA_11_18_New
1  X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE Not applicable     Not applicable
2  k5   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3      TRUE           TRUE                  1
3 N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA      TRUE Not applicable                  2
4 N40    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2     FALSE Not applicable                  2
5  K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90      TRUE           TRUE                  0
6 S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10      TRUE Not applicable                  1
7  K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE          FALSE     Not applicable
8  K5   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9     FALSE          FALSE     Not applicable

For example, in row 2 I have at least 6 consecutive Non-NA values from K_11 up to K18, so the column "Con_11_18" takes the value "TRUE".
For the first row, this is not the case, so that column takes the value "FALSE".
The column "Con_11_18_New" is a repetition of column "con_11_18" with the only difference that it focuces only on rows where New=k5,
and for all other rows it takes the value "Not applicable".
The third row focuses only on the rows for which we have at least 6 consecutive Non-Nas between K_11 and K_18 and counts the NAs within that interval. For example,in row 2, where we have at least 6 consecutive Non-Nas, we have 1 NA between K_11 and K_18. In row 3, we have 2 such NAs. For the rows for which
we do not have 6 consecutive Non-Nas they are assigned the value "Not applicable"
I know it is a bit difficult what I ask, but If you can provide some general code that would be great. Note that my real data set contains
thousands of rows.
To be honest I am not even sure how to begin solving this problem, that's why I need your help

Here is a base R approach:
fn <- function(x){
  idx <- !is.na(x)
  max(rle(diff(cumsum(idx)))$lengths) * (max(idx)>0)
}

nms <- names(df)
d <- df[, which(nms == 'K_11') : which(nms == 'K_18')]

within(df, 
       {Con_11_18 <- apply(d , 1, fn) >= 6
      count_NA_11_18_New <- rowSums(is.na(d))
      Con_11_18_New <- ifelse(tolower(df$New)== 'k5', Con_11_18, 'not applicable')
      count_NA_11_18_New <- ifelse(Con_11_18, count_NA_11_18_New, 'not applicable')}
)
  New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23  Con_11_18_New count_NA_11_18_New Con_11_18
1  X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA not applicable     not applicable     FALSE
2  k5   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3           TRUE                  1      TRUE
3 N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA not applicable                  2      TRUE
4 N40    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2 not applicable     not applicable     FALSE
5  K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90           TRUE                  0      TRUE
6 S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10 not applicable                  1      TRUE
7  K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA          FALSE     not applicable     FALSE
8  K5   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9          FALSE     not applicable     FALSE


Here is a tidyverse approach of the same:
df %>%
  mutate( Con_11_18 = matrixStats::colCumsums(t(!is.na(pick(K_11:K_18))))|>
                      apply(2, \(x)max(rle(diff(x))$lengths) * (max(x)>0)) >= 6, 
          Con_11_18_New = ifelse(tolower(New)== 'k5', Con_11_18, 'not applicable'),
          count_NA_11_18_New = rowSums(is.na(pick(K_11:K_18))),
          count_NA_11_18_New = ifelse(Con_11_18, count_NA_11_18_New, 'not applicable')
  )


@Iroha are you sure? Check the results.  you can use sum to determine consecutive numbers after finding difference with lag 1. Check the code again

@Iroha. The issue is not because of colSums but rather because I did not take out the 0. Let me update the solution, still using the same

@Iroha the issue was not with colCumsums but rather with colSums. Thanks for the input

ThanK you Onyambu, very much. If I want to modify the above code to get, for example, at most 5 consecutive Non-NA values, how could it be modified?  I am asking this because it is good to know how to play with the code. Thank you again!

@newfinder change 6 to 5 in the code

It seems that it gives me at leat 5? If I want up to 5?

@newfinder use ==5

Yes it works.! May I ask two more questions? A) If I want, say exactly 5? B) If want betwen, say, 2 and 5? I might need these in the future and I want to take into account all possible scenaria now that the answers are hot!.Thank you so much again!!

@newfinder This does not answer that. You may have to ask a new question for that

I created a similar question, if you could help me.  I also noticed that ==5 does not work for the case of "at most 5"

You could try any together with rle. Combining booleans like TRUE with strings doesn't make sense, just use booleans.
> chk_con <- \(x, cols, min) {
+   any(with(rle(x), lengths[values == 'FALSE']) > min - 1L)
+ }
> df |>
+   transform(cns_11_18=apply(is.na(df[paste('K', 11:18, sep='_')]), 1, chk_con, min=6L))
  New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23 cns_11_18
1  X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE
2  k5   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3      TRUE
3 N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA      TRUE
4 N40    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2     FALSE
5  K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90      TRUE
6 S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10      TRUE
7  K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE
8  K5   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9     FALSE

Update
> chk_upto <- \(x, cols, max) {
+   rl <- rle(x)
+   fls <- with(rl, lengths[!values])
+   if (length(fls)) {
+     all(fls > 1) & all(fls < max + 1L)
+   } else {
+     FALSE
+   }
+ }
> df2 |>
+   transform(cns_11_18=apply(is.na(df2[-1]), 1, chk_upto, max=6L))
  New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23 cns_11_18
1  X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE
2  k5    2    2    2    3    3    2    2    5    6    3    3    3    3    3     FALSE
3 N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA     FALSE
4 N40    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2    2   NA    2    2    2      TRUE
5  K5    0    0    0    0   10   NA   43    1   NA    3    6   NA    9   90      TRUE
6 S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   NA   10   10   10   10   NA   10     FALSE
7  K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE
8  K5   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9     FALSE


Data:
> dput(df2)
structure(list(New = c("X2", "k5", "N30", "N40", "K5", "S12", 
"K5", "K5"), K_10 = c(NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L, NA, NA), K_11 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, 4L, 0L, 3L, NA, NA), K_12 = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
NA, 0L), K_13 = c(0L, 3L, 5L, NA, 0L, 5L, NA, NA), K_14 = c(NA, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 10L, NA, NA), K_15 = c(NA, 2L, 3L, 5L, NA, 10L, 
NA, 2L), K_16 = c(NA, 2L, 1L, 6L, 43L, 10L, NA, 56L), K_17 = c(NA, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, 23L), K_18 = c(NA, 6L, 4L, 2L, NA, 10L, 
NA, 12L), K_19 = c(NA, 3L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 10L, NA, 90L), K_20 = c(NA, 
3L, 19L, NA, 6L, 10L, NA, 59L), K_21 = c(NA, 3L, 10L, 2L, NA, 
10L, NA, 11L), K_22 = c(NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 9L, NA, NA, 10L), K_23 = c(NA, 
3L, NA, 2L, 90L, 10L, NA, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))


ThanK you Jay.sf, very much. If I want to modify the above code to get, for example, at most 5 consecutive Non-NA values, how could it be modified? I am asking this because it is good to know how to play with the code. Thank you again!

@newfinder You can simply use min=6L .  Actually I included this argument to make it flexible and forgot to explain!

Do you mean min=5L?I tried this but it gives me "at least 5". If I want up to 5 consecutive numerical values?

@newfinder not sure, currently not at the machine, maybe you can tweak it to get what you want.

If you happen to be at the mahine,  do not forget me. If I have to, I will create a new question!

@newfinder see update, hope it works.

Thank you very much Jay.sf. This corresponds to the case "up to 5" or "exactly 5"?.

Yes, it hopefully does, @newfinder, test it.

I created a similar question, if you could help me.  I also noticed that the above update does not work for the case of "at most 5". See my new question. Many thanks!

I just love these types of questions. I don't know if it's as efficient as the first answer, but it feels pretty transparent. I just learned about rle() from this other question here.
# Helper function
max.non.na.span <- function(x) {
  # return max non-NA length <numeric>
  # or return NA if all NA
  if (all(is.na(x))) return(NA)
  rle.res <- rle(!(is.na(x)))
  non.na.lengths <- rle.res$lengths[rle.res$values]
  max(non.na.lengths)
}

# Iterate through "New" column and a list of the 11->18 row
# slices of the data.frame simultaneously, returning a list of
# data.frame rows that we'll put together with rbind
new.df.cols <- base::Map(
  df$New,
  split(as.matrix(df[, paste0("K_", 11:18)]), row(df[, paste0("K_", 11:18)])),
  f = \(x, y) {
    Con_11_18 <- local({
      max.non.na.len <- max.non.na.span(y)
      if (is.na(max.non.na.len)) return(FALSE)
      ifelse(max.non.na.len >= 6, TRUE, FALSE)
    })
    Con_11_18_New <- local({
      if (tolower(x) %in% "k5") return(Con_11_18)
      NA
    })
    count_NA_11_18_New <- local({
      if (Con_11_18) return(sum(is.na(y)))
      NA
    })
    data.frame(
      Con_11_18 = Con_11_18,
      Con_11_18_New = Con_11_18_New,
      count_NA_11_18_New = count_NA_11_18_New
    )
  }
) |> do.call(rbind, args = _) |> base::transform(row.names = NULL)

df_new_new <- cbind(df, new.df.cols)

df_new_new
  New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23 Con_11_18 Con_11_18_New count_NA_11_18_New
1  X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE            NA                 NA
2  k5   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3      TRUE          TRUE                  1
3 N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA      TRUE            NA                  2
4 N40    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2     FALSE            NA                 NA
5  K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90      TRUE          TRUE                  0
6 S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10      TRUE            NA                  1
7  K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE         FALSE                 NA
8  K5   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9     FALSE         FALSE                 NA

